# Remove Unused CSS Selectors other than 'Dust Me Selectors'?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to remove all unused CSS selectors from a common CSS file. While the Firefox extension "Dust Me Selectors" works well, it only works per page. It reports unused selectors for a page but some could be used on other pages.

Is there a tool which can go through a folder, scan all the files and bring up a list of selectors which are not used anywhere?

Comment: Dust-me can not be installed on FF8 :( Any ideas how can I use without downgrade FF?

Comment: latest version (3.0.1) is working for me on FF 12...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why you can't use Dust Me Selectors, you can right-click on the symbol and select "Spider Sitemap" to do an entire website at once.

Comment: It works if I have a sitemap or the pages are linked. In some cases I don't have these.

Comment: @abdu, then you should build one. All sites should have one for google  (I mean searchengines) anyway.

Comment: Dust Me Selectors has a well-known bug in that sometimes it will freeze or ignore pages when the spider option is used.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to me that Dust-Me doesn't really "spider", to the extent that it only follows the links it is given in the site map; it doesn't continue by following the next level of links contained in those pages. So you site map has to be complete. I also have a concern that Dust-Me is only concerned with unused selectors in the HTML. I'm working on a project where some selectors in the CSS are used in Javascript, but are not mentioned directly in the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but people can also use [CSS Usage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/) for Firebug in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

There is now the option of [purifycss](https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss), which has a CLI and can be used inside NodeJs.

Didn't found as IDE extensions, but being npm-friendly that wouldn't be a problem.